# Decompile angular elements

Tags: angularjs

We have a angular grid written by some guys here at work, the entire company uses it.
A td-cell could look like this

```
<td typeahead-cell="location as location.Name for location in getApiLocations($viewValue, mapping)" ng-model="mapping.selectedLocation">
    {{mapping.getLocationNames()}}
</td>
```

The `typeahead-cell` directive will execute some custom code on the td, what it does is hookup some code so that if you double click or write in the cell it will go from display only to (in this case) typeahead. It does this by taking the html in the td cell (The td cell is already compiled by angular), wrap it with some custom code that does above functioanlly and then call $compile on the entire thing. This works with expressions above like `{{mapping.getLocationNames()}}` because they do not change when compiling so it can be compiled any number of times.

The problem I face now is that I try to use a more complex expression with `ng-repeat`. Problem is the first compile (Done directly by angular-core) will change html from example

from

```
<span ng-repeat="location in mapping.locations">...</span>
```

to

```
<!-- ngRepeat: location in mapping.locations -->
```

Then when our custom grid code executs it will try to compile the code above which will result in an empty since it compiles against a html comment.

This is the code that breaks

```
$element.html($compile(displayElement.html($element.html()))($scope));
```

$element is the td-cell that contains my orignal code that, when doing `$element.html()` it will take compiled code and try to use that. Wont work. Displayelement is a wrapper that will show when we are in displaymode.

I either need to decompile `$element`befor edoing `$element.html` or somehow move the content of the $element (td cell) compiled and hooked up.

Any ideas?

**edit:** I have somewhat solved it, doing this

```
$element.children().appendTo(displayElement);
displayElement.appendTo($element);
```

This will take the children from the td-cell and add them to the displayElement without actually breaking the original `$compile`. `jQuery.children` cant move `<!-- comment -->` elements so if you have an expression with ng directives like my repater above you need to wrap it in a dummy element like

```
<span><span ng-repeat="location in mapping.locations">...</span></span>
```

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution is this

```
$element.contents().appendTo(displayElement);
displayElement.appendTo($element);
```

It's very important to use `contents` and not `children` because `children`will ignore text nodes which will not include the comments generated by `ng-repeat` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Instated of that line if you can check with this

```
//Store it first on a variable if blank
var html;
if(!html) html = displayElement.html($element.html()); 
$element.html($compile(html)($scope));
```

Hopefully it will work. May be you need to manage the scope of the variable.

Comment: This wont work, $element.html() because angular has already compiled it for you, see my edit